# Archivos de configuracion de MYSQL 8 en Ubuntu 22

Tags: mysql

Hola a todos estoy un poco confundido a la hora de hacer unas configuraciones en MYSQL. Veo muchos ejemplos de ellas por ahí pero cada uno de ellos pone un archivo distinto de MYSQL.
Por ejemplo:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/my.cnf //este no lo tengo yo, no se me creo en la instalación
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf/..
```

Luego en el directorio /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d volvemos a tener los archivos mysql.cnf  mysqld.cnf. Lo que me lleva a tener incluso configuraciones duplicadas en varios archivos, por ejemplo:

```
[mysql]
local-infile = 1
[mysqld]
#allow INTO OUTFILE file and LOAD DATA INFILE to this directory
local-infile = 1
secure_file_priv =  /home/LOTES/
```

Esto lo tengo en /etc/mysql/my.cnf y /etc/mysql/mysql.conf. Entonces cual es la direncia entre los archivos /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/mysql.conf y los que estan dentro del directorio  mysql.conf.d.